Cannot share a class in multiprocessing
I'm trying to create a test program that shares a given class object in Python 3 multiprocessing.
For doing this I create first a class object and then apply  manager.Value to it in order to get the shared object.
The problem is that the shared object seems not to be the same object in memory outside and inside the process.
Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?
The code of the application is:
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def set(self, val):
        print(f'set({val})')
        self.val= val

    def get(self):
        return self.val

def modify(args):
    shared, v = args
    print(f'prev, get()= {shared.value.get()}')
    shared.value.set(v)
    print(f'after, get()= {shared.value.get()}')

def main5():
    manager = Manager()
    myclass = MyClass(-1)
    shared = manager.Value('c', myclass)
    pool = Pool(1)
    params = []
    for v in range(5, 6):
        params.append((shared, v))
    pool.imap(func=modify, iterable=params)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print("Valor modificado:", shared.value.get())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    main5()

And the output is:
prev, get()= -1
set(5)
after, get()= -1
Last value stored: -1


what exactly are you trying to share ? sharing something very generic is (while possible) usually either slow or complicated, if you just want to share a simple counter you should be using multiprocessing.Value, for a complicated class you need to create and register a proxy ... which gets more or less involved based on actual use case.

Well, this is only an example. In the real case, what I have is a very complicated class with specific methods to populate itself with data, and I want to use it on every process.

sharing a simple counter should be done by passing around multiprocessing.Value, but for a complicated class you need to create a proxy that will be registered to a Manager.
the following code shows how to do it for your simple class, as you see there is a lot of code duplication.
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager, BaseProxy

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def set(self, val):
        print(f'set({val})')
        self.val = val

    def get(self):
        return self.val

class MyClassProxy(BaseProxy):
    _exposed_ = ['get', 'set']

    def get(self):
        return self._callmethod('get')

    def set(self, value):
        return self._callmethod('set', (value,))

SyncManager.register("MyClass", MyClass, MyClassProxy)

def modify(args):
    shared, v = args
    print(f'prev, get()= {shared.get()}')
    shared.set(v)
    print(f'after, get()= {shared.get()}')

def main5():
    manager = SyncManager()
    manager.start()
    shared = manager.MyClass(-1)
    pool = Pool(1)
    params = []
    for v in range(5, 6):
        params.append((shared, v))
    pool.imap(func=modify, iterable=params)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print("Valor modificado:", shared.get())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    main5()

prev, get()= -1
set(5)
after, get()= 5
Valor modificado: 5

note that you cannot access any attributes, you can only call methods on the shared object, this also involves a lot of IPC, so i would instead recommend using multiprocessing.Value and multiprocessing.Array whenever possible, but they can only store basic C datatypes, not complicated python classes.
